# yarn list deduped with licenses

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to get a list of packages used with their license types, but `yarn list` produces a list with many duplicates and there appears to be no option for appending license information. Basically I'm looking for something like

```
$ yarn list
abab    W3C 3-clause BSD License
abbrev  ISC
accepts MIT
.
.
.
etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/license-checker) for this apparently. Once `license-checker` is installed one only needs to

```
license-checker --csv --out licenses.csv
```

to get exactly the desired file.